# How can I lay moulding around this ceiling protrusion?

Tags: ceiling, trim

We are installing crown moulding in our kitchen.  The ceiling is horizontal so we haven't had much difficulty.  Except for this part:

[image: my kitchen ceiling]

That sloped part of the wall is the underside of the staircase going to the floor above.  How do we put moulding around that?

One idea would be to just put quarter round between the ceiling and the sloped part.  Quarter round is what was up there before.  That would at least cover the joint between the wall and the ceiling, but the sloped wall might stick out like a sore thumb.

Another would be to frame out the sloped wall so that it's vertical near the ceiling, then install crown moulding around it.  But that seems like it might be kind of bulky, and a lot of work.

Any other, better ideas?

Comment: Without fabricating a custom profile, an angled moulding will not line up with a vertical moulding, and it will be near impossible to come up with a seamless transition. So, getting the gypsum board right is going to be less work in the long run compared to anything other than not caring that it doesn't look seamless. Gypsum board is also easy to work with. I'd start by considering dropping down the height of the moulding and then tapering back at an angle similar to existing. In the end however, it's always going to look off simply because the stair intrudes into the room.

Comment: @benrudgers - If you look closely at the picture, it appears that the walls are paneling, not gypsum board. The OP may want to confirm this though.

Comment: Yes, the walls are paneling.

Comment: I would just put a bottom on the crown and continue on at 90 degrees.

Comment: @DMoore About 5 years ago we did a complete reno with professional carpenters. All these walls are gone now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might not have to create a fully vertical face to apply your crown. Crown molding is usually either 38 or 45 degrees (with some exceptions, so make sure and check) and it looks like the wall angle is greater than that so all you need to do is create a flat spot for the foot of the crown to land on. Here's a drawing:

[image]

I wouldn't recommend 1/4 round because it always looks like you're trying to fix a mistake and it shows all the inconsistencies in the wall/ceiling. Hope this helps.

Comment: You know I was just looking at this and it occurred to me that you might have to wrap the filler around the corner to make the crown line up properly. Just a heads up.

Comment: Nope won't need to, see below

Comment: In the end my father in law rigged something which looks nice, albeit is not seamless. This is what I would have gone with had I been working alone. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a repeat but it is a picture of what I have done.

I also cut the top of the crown carefully into the sloped part to reduce the filler at the bottom edge.[image]

[image]